# How do I pass the descriptor as an integer to a function?

Tags: c

I need to count the occurrences of a specific character in a file, the definition of the function to perform the search is as follows:

```cpp
int countChar(int descriptor, char *charsearch);
```

At compiler time, I have the following error:

```
program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:14:89: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘countChar’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  printf("The character %s has been found %d times in the file %s.", argv[1], countChar(o_file, argv[1]), argv[2]);
program.c:4:19: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘FILE *’
  int countChar(int descriptor, char *charsearch);
programa.c: In function ‘countChar’:
programa.c:25:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  if ( leido == charsearch){
```

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *o_file;
int countChar(int descriptor, char *charsearch);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *o_file = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (!o_file){
        printf("Cannot open file %s.", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("File %s open \n", argv[2]);
        printf("Searching for %s ...\n", argv[1]);
        printf("The character %s has been found %d times in the file %s.", argv[1], countChar(o_file, argv[1]), argv[2]);
    }
    fclose(o_file);
    printf("File %s closed", argv[2]);
}

int countChar(int descriptor, char *charsearch){
    int counting = 0;
    do {
        int leido = fgetc(o_file);
        if (leido != EOF){
            if ( leido == charsearch){
                counting ++;
            }
        }
    } while (!feof(o_file));
    return counting;
}
```

Comment: what's descriptor supposed to do? just make it a FILE* arg in the signature

Comment: `countChar` doesn't even use its `descriptor` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `FILE*` pointer is not a file descriptor, it is a file stream. `FILE*` is not compatible with your function declaration. Change the function to take a `FILE*` instead of an `int` in the first parameter, especially since the function is calling system functions that take `FILE*` as input anyway.

You should also change the second parameter from `char*` to `char`, since you are searching for a single character only, not a string.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int countChar(FILE* f, char charsearch);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *o_file = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if (!o_file){
        printf("Cannot open file %s.", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("File %s open \n", argv[2]);
    printf("Searching for %s ...\n", argv[1]);
    printf("The character %c has been found %d times in the file %s.", argv[1][0], countChar(o_file, argv[1][0]), argv[2]);
    fclose(o_file);
    printf("File %s closed", argv[2]);
}

int countChar(FILE *f, char charsearch){
    int counting = 0;
    do {
        int leido = fgetc(f);
        if (leido != EOF){
            if (leido == charsearch){
                ++counting;
            }
        }
    } while (!feof(f));
    return counting;
}
```

If you are not allowed to change the signature of the function, then you have to use `open()` instead of `fopen()`, and `read()` instead of `fgetc()`.  And also, dereference the `char*` during the loop comparisons:

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int countChar(int descriptor, char* charsearch);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int fd = open(argv[2], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1){
        printf("Cannot open file %s.", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("File %s open \n", argv[2]);
    printf("Searching for %s ...\n", argv[1]);
    printf("The character %s has been found %d times in the file %s.", argv[1], countChar(fd, argv[1]), argv[2]);
    close(fd);
    printf("File %s closed", argv[2]);
}

int countChar(int descriptor, char* charsearch){
    int counting = 0;
    char leido;
    while (read(descriptor, &leido, 1) == 1){
        if (leido == *charsearch){
            ++counting;
        }
    }
    return counting;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was necessary to make use of the POSIX functions.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in `o_file`, which has type `FILE *`, not type `int`. Try `int countChar(FILE * descriptor, char *charsearch);`. Also, you should refer to `descriptor` instead of `o_file` inside `countChar` (or drop `descriptor` entirely from the call and signature).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a file descriptor that you could pass to your function.  You have a *stream*, represented by a `FILE` object.  You can easily pass the pointer to that object to your function if you are permitted to change its signature:

```
int countChar(FILE *descriptor, char *charsearch);
```

---

Alternatively, if you are required to use the signature given in the question then that suggests that you are opening the file the wrong way.  If you need an integer file descriptor representing the open file, then you should open it with `open()` instead of with `fopen()`.  Do understand, however, that whereas the latter is part of the C language specification, the former is instead standardized as part of POSIX, so it is available only from certain C implementations -- those for UNIX-ish systems, for the most part, such as Linux and macOS.